# Include none letter characters in regex search

Tags: php, regex

I have a working regex code, but it's not including the non-letter characters. How would I include those?

```
$text = "i have one treehouse. i'm the one. I have two cats.";
preg_match_all('/[\w\s]+?\bone\s?[\w\s]*?\./', $text, $array);

print_r($array);
```

**Expected Results**

```
$array[0] = "i have one treehouse.";
$array[1] = "i'm the one";
```

**Actual Results**

```
$array[0] = "i have one treehouse.";
$array[1] = "m the one"; <---cuts off at the single quote
```

I think it's because the regex code doesn't look for non-letter characters like ',!? and so on. How do I include those?

Comment: You're using a character group currently: `[\w\s]`. To that, add the special characters you want to include: `[\w\s',!]`

Comment: Wait. I saw a similar post sometime ago I think

Comment: `[]` is a character class listing characters you want. Put the characters you are allowing inside it.

Comment: What if you try with `(?<=[.?!])\s+(?=\w)`? See [demo](http://ideone.com/SDjCci).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to  include `'` inside the character class.

```
\b[\w'\s]+?\bone\s?[\w\s]*?\.
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yG6wZ5/2)

```
preg_match_all("~\b[\w'\s]+?\bone\s?[\w\s]*?\.~", $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Can you include the whole preg_match_all? I'm having trouble placing where this part of the code goes.

Comment: I need it to match it if the sentence ends with a question mark, or a exclamation mark too.

Comment: I also don't want it to cut off at commas.